# The Maven Central repository search returns only 20 versions. Any way to get all the versions possible?

Tags: java, spring, maven, solr

The solr search API call is resitricting the list of versions to only 20. Why? And how do we get the list of all the versions released for the GAV coorsinates. Any API call?

https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:com.fasterxml.jackson.coreAND+a:jackson-databind&core=gav&rows=10000&wt=json

Could you please help in finding an API which can let me have access to all the versions and their release dates for a GAV coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

It's paginated. You can add an additional query parameter to get the 2nd page `&start=20`

The response contains the total number of records: `"response":{"numFound":189` so you will have to keep sending requests and incrementing the value of `start` until you've got them all.

In this case, it would take 10 requests.

The reason they enforce pagination is because constructing a big response is expensive. If there were a million results, the response would be gigantic. It would be easy for malicious users (or honest users who made a mistake) to send requests which would cause the server to struggle, or even bring it down entirely. By enforcing pagination as mandatory, it forces the people making requests to be more thoughtful about what they're requesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. Change the dots `.` in `groupId` to slashes `/` . Then execute url with the following format `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/(groupId with slash)/(artifactId)`. You will get its information including versions. Then you can select `maven-metadata.xml` or add copy url above `/maven-metadata.xml` to get xml.

Your example in this case is: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/maven-metadata.xml